# 52/5000 How to get a certain value in html code by c #

Tags: c#

i want search spacial value in html code by webbrowser in c#. for example  html code`<span class="pulser " data-dollari="164.843956376000000" eq_toman="_XcUOV" pulser-change="_OiuVD" pre-dollari="164.964899983000000">$164.97</span>`i need Getting the value "164.964899983000000" and another value html code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get an element from a site and get its attribute values like 'pre-dollari'.

For c#, you can use [ScrapySharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ScrapySharp) , it's a library where you can simulate a webbrowser and scrape its contents. You can use it alongside [htmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)
to effectively traverse the elements.

So for your case, it could look like this.

```
// get your Url
Uri url = new Uri("Yoursite.com");
// open up the browser
ScrapingBrowser browser = new ScrapingBrowser();
// navigate to your page
WebPage page = browser.NavigateToPage(url, HttpVerb.Post, "", null);
// find your element, convert to a list and take the first result [0]
HtmlNode node2 = page.Find("span", By.Class("pulser")).ToList()[0];
// and now you can get the attribute by name and put it in a variable
string attributeValue = node2.GetAttributeValue("pre-dollari", "not found"); 
// attributeValue = 164.964899983000000
```